# pip install a local git repository

Tags: python, git, pip

I can't find the correct way to install a local directory as a python package using pip.

```
(venv) C:\(...)>pip install . --no-index
Ignoring indexes: http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Unpacking c:\users\fsantos\desktop\biskates.com\biskates\forks\django-pipeline
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///(...)%5Cforks%5Cdjango-pipeline

Installing collected packages: django-pipeline
  Running setup.py install for django-pipeline

Successfully installed django-pipeline
Cleaning up...

(venv) C:\(...)>cd ..
(venv) C:\(...)>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pipeline
>>> pipeline.__file__
'C:\\(...)site-packages\\pipeline\\__init__.py'
>>>
```

As you can see pip just copied over the package to site-packages. How can I avoid this, and use the package directly from its source folder?

I'm trying to integrate django-pipeline into my Django project, but I want to add support for Django 1.4 first, so I forked and cloned my fork.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I can also just use:

```
cd your-local-repo
pip install -e .
```

or

```
python setup.py install develop
```

Comment: my purpose was only for development, bit this is a pretty good answer. This should also work on a requirements.txt in a virtualenv.

Comment: Awesome solution! How do I then uninstall when changes are merged into the main repo?

Comment: @FábioSantos The `-e` was the only missing part in your story and you should mark this answer as the correct one IMO.

Comment: Reading this years later, this is indeed the correct answer. Sorry it took me so long :)

Comment: the command should be `python setup.py develop` instead of `python setup.py install develop`. IOW, `install` should not be there. See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html

Answer (score 107):

If you're working in a `venv`, you can do this:

```
env/bin/pip install git+file:///path/to/your/git/repo
```

Or with a branch:

```
env/bin/pip install git+file:///path/to/your/git/repo@mybranch
```

Comment: The question was about installing an actual directory (because I was developing two very closely related projects and I wanted to code on both when debugging), but this is a nice reminder of what can be done!

Comment: Mike, thanks! This helped me a lot. I had some git+ssh private dependencies and the repository server went to maintenance.

Comment: It is very important to note that there are **3** `/` after `git+file:`

Comment: What is the advantage of `env/bin/pip` over the usual `python -m pip` ?

Comment: Relative paths `file:///../my-repo` did not work, however absolute paths did `file:///Users/me/my-repo`

Answer (score 14):

You can use **pip** or **pipenv** with the following command to install from a local git repo:

```
pip install git+file:///path/to/your/package#egg=package-name
```

*Note that there are 3 slashes after file: here.*

To install from a remote repo use:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com:Username/Project.git
```

You can also specify a desired branch like so:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com:Username/Project.git@master
```

I just rounded up the previous answers and comments from [Quilt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4285617/quilt) and [nanounanue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754176/nanounanue) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883430/trouble-installing-private-github-repository-using-pip). Also posted it [here](https://kozyatnikov.com/how-to-pip-install-local-package).