# Issues in installing a private git repo using pip

Tags: git, github, ssh, pip

I am trying to install a package from a private repository that I have access to using pip.

I am able to directly clone it.

But when I try to install it via pip, I am getting below error:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128:
  command: git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/my_projects/ib_client' /tmp/pip-req-
  build-ivumdv23
  cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  key_load_public: invalid format
  Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'AA.BB.CC.DD' to the list 
  of known hosts.
  Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 
  'ssh://****@github.com/my_projects/ib_client' /tmp/pip-req-build-ivumdv23 Check 
  the logs for full command output.
  The command '/bin/sh -c python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip     && python3 -m pip install -q -r ${BASE_DIR}/requirements.txt     && python3 -m pip install -q -r ${BASE_DIR}/healthchecks/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
  make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Regarding same, I have gone through the posts: [Trouble installing private github repository using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883430/trouble-installing-private-github-repository-using-pip) , [Is it possible to use pip to install a package from a private GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository) and [Trouble installing private github repository using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883430/trouble-installing-private-github-repository-using-pip?noredirect=1&lq=1), but still I am unable to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Looks like you have a ssh problem (let's add the "ssh" tag). Not a Python/pip problem, nor a git problem. First figure out how to correctly configure your ssh client to reliably connect to the host of the git repository `ssh git@github.com`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+key_load_public%3A+invalid+format

Comment: @sinoroc  Thanks for your response. I have added this IP and hostname in ~/.ssh/known_hosts and restarted ssh daemon. But still the problem persists.

Comment: @Joy you need to address the `key_load_public: invalid format` issue. I don't believe it has anything to do with `known_hosts` or even less so with your SSH daemon (you need to fix the configuration of your SSH client, not your SSH server). Check that your public-private key pair is correct. Are you usually able to connect to `ssh git@github.com`? Are you usually able to clone this private git repository?