# Celery missing 1 required positional argument on python task

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I have a celery beat running under my workspace once per minute. My task is very simple:

```
@task()
def capturar_placas():
    print('Iniciando Captura de Placas do OpenALPR CLOUD')
```

But each time celery try to execute my task i got the following error:

```
File "/home/ronaldo.lanhellas/workspace/github/safepark/pythonvenv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/django/models.py", line 29, in Message
    queue = models.ForeignKey(Queue, related_name='messages')
celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task Capturar Placas: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Looking at "models.py" from kombu lib i noted that don't exists on_delete argument in FK, but Django 2.x require it. How can i solve that ? Update library maybe ?

Comment: Somebody has [tried a pull request](https://github.com/celery/kombu/pull/892) to fix this issue. Your best bet is to post [your issue on github](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues) or create a PR yourself (based on the one I just linked to).

Comment: How can i create a local version of this library with this fix ?

Comment: You can install it ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134362/308204)) and then adapt the code. If you get it working, I'm sure the repository maintainers would like to see a PR from you.