# How to use pip to install a specific branch of a local repository in editable/develop mode?

Tags: python, git, pip

I am imagining something like

```
pip install -e Path/to/Repo@Branch
```

The repository is on my local machine so that I can edit it and don't need to reinstall it over and over.

How can I do it? Thank you ahead for your answering.

Someone proposes the solution of "env/bin/pip install git+file:///path/to/your/git/repo" in this question [pip install a local git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159482/pip-install-a-local-git-repository)
This doesn't work because I want to install in "DEVELOP" mode. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install+local+repository

Answer (score 0):

If you’re working from a virtual environment, you can do the following:

```
env/bin/pip install git+file:///path/to/your/git/repo
```

Or a specific branch

```
env/bin/pip install git+file:///path/to/your/git/repo@mybranch
```

Credit to Quilt for their answer here: [pip install a local git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159482/pip-install-a-local-git-repository)